# How to avoid Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 AuthorizedOnly" in MAC OS

Tags: macos, slack, slack-api, http-proxy

I am trying connecting with Slack API from my MAC using Eclipse and Java. 
But the same code is working in Windows. In MAC OS it is throwing below error:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "https://slack.com/api/rtm.connect": Unable to tunnel
>   through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 AuthorizedOnly"; nested
>   exception is java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy.
>   Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 AuthorizedOnly"

Comment: Looks like your proxy does not allow Websockets. RTM is not using HTTP, but the Websockets protocol. Have you checked that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Yes You are correct. I am not able to make a websocket connection. But as soon as I came out of VPN, websocket connection is successful but then I cannot access Slack as it can only be accessed in VPN network